# Which Linux kernel function creates the 'process 0'?

Tags: c, assembly, linux-kernel, x86, boot

I'm trying to understand more about `process 0`, such as, whether it has a memory descriptor (non-`NULL` `task_struct->mm` field) or not, and how is it related to the swap or idle process. It seems to me that a single 'process 0' is created on the boot cpu, and then an idle thread is created for every other cpu by [`idle_threads_init`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.7/source/kernel/smpboot.c#L67), but I didn't find where the first one( I assume that is the `process 0`) was created.

**Update**

In light of the [live book](https://github.com/0xAX/linux-insides/blob/master/SUMMARY.md) that tychen referenced, here is my most up-to-date understanding regarding `process 0` (for x86_64), can someone confirm/refute the items below?

1. An [`init_task`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.7/source/init/init_task.c#L57) typed `task_struct` is statically defined, with the task's kernel stack `init_task.stack = init_stack`, memory descriptor `init_task.mm=NULL` and `init_task.active_mm=&init_mm`, where the stack area [`init_stack`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.7/source/include/asm-generic/vmlinux.lds.h#L359) and `mm_struct` [`init_mm`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.7/source/mm/init-mm.c#L29) are both statically defined.
2. The fact that only `active_mm` is non-NULL means `process 0` is a kernel process. Also, [`init_task.flags=PF_KTHREAD`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.7/source/init/init_task.c#L69).
3. Not long after the uncompressed kernel image begins execution, boot cpu [starts](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.7/source/arch/x86/kernel/head_64.S#L167) to use `init_stack` as kernel stack. This makes the `current` macro meaningful (for the first time since machine boots up), which makes `fork()` possible. After this point, the kernel literally runs in `process 0`'s conext.
4. [`start_kernel`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.7/source/init/main.c#L828) -> [`arch_call_rest_init`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.7/source/init/main.c#L823) -> [`rest_init`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.7/source/init/main.c#L658), and inside this function, `process 1&2` are forked. Within the [`kernel_init`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.7/source/init/main.c#L1392) function which is scheduled for `process 1`, a new thread (with [`CLONE_VM`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.7/source/kernel/fork.c#L2378)) is made and hooked to a CPU's run queue's `rq->idle`, for every other logical CPU.
5. Interestingly, all idle threads share the same `tid 0` (not only `tgid`). Usually threads share `tgid` but have distinct `tid`, which is really Linux's `process id`. I guess it doesn't break anything because idle threads are locked to their own CPUs.
6. `kernel_init` loads the `init` executable (typically `/sbin/init`), and switches both `current`->`mm` and `active_mm` to a non-NULL `mm_struct`, and clears the `PF_KTHREAD` flag, which makes `process 1` a legitimate user space process. While `process 2` does not tweak `mm`, meaning it remains a kernel process, same as `process 0`.
7. At the end of `rest_init`, `do_idle` takes over, which means all CPU has an idle process.
8. Something confused me before, but now becomes clear: the `init_*` objects/labels such as `init_task`/`init_mm`/`init_stack` are all used by `process 0`, and not the `init process`, which is `process 1`.

Comment: Please don't edit an answer into the question.  Post it as an answer where it can get upvotes separately from the question.  (And at some point in the future if it becomes outdated, isn't placed above other answers.)

Comment: Ok. There are stuff that I am not sure hence they appear in the question, but what you said makes sense. I can put them in a separate answer thread to gather feedback.

Comment: Oh, if this is still something you're asking for confirmation of, and aren't sure is right, then being in the question makes sense.

Comment: Ok, I'll be explicit about it in the text then.

Answer (score 3):

We really start Linux kernel from [`start_kernel`](https://code.woboq.org/linux/linux/init/main.c.html#start_kernel), and the process 0/idle starts here too.

In the begin of `start_kernel`, we call `set_task_stack_end_magic(&init_stack)`. This function will set the stack border of  [`init_task`](https://code.woboq.org/linux/linux/init/init_task.c.html#init_task), which is the process 0/idle.

```c
void set_task_stack_end_magic(struct task_struct *tsk)
{
    unsigned long *stackend;

    stackend = end_of_stack(tsk);
    *stackend = STACK_END_MAGIC;    /* for overflow detection */
}
```

It's easy to understand that this function get the limitation address and set the bottom to STACK_END_MAGIC as a stack overflow flag. Here is the structure graph.

[image]

The process 0 is statically defined . This is the only process that is not created by `kernel_thread` nor `fork`.

```c
/*
 * Set up the first task table, touch at your own risk!. Base=0,
 * limit=0x1fffff (=2MB)
 */
struct task_struct init_task
#ifdef CONFIG_ARCH_TASK_STRUCT_ON_STACK
    __init_task_data
#endif
= {
#ifdef CONFIG_THREAD_INFO_IN_TASK
    .thread_info    = INIT_THREAD_INFO(init_task),
    .stack_refcount = REFCOUNT_INIT(1),
#endif
    .state      = 0,
    .stack      = init_stack,
    .usage      = REFCOUNT_INIT(2),
    .flags      = PF_KTHREAD,
    .prio       = MAX_PRIO - 20,
    .static_prio    = MAX_PRIO - 20,
    .normal_prio    = MAX_PRIO - 20,
    .policy     = SCHED_NORMAL,
    .cpus_ptr   = &init_task.cpus_mask,
    .cpus_mask  = CPU_MASK_ALL,
    .nr_cpus_allowed= NR_CPUS,
    .mm     = NULL,
    .active_mm  = &init_mm,
    ......
    .thread_pid = &init_struct_pid,
    .thread_group   = LIST_HEAD_INIT(init_task.thread_group),
    .thread_node    = LIST_HEAD_INIT(init_signals.thread_head),
    ......
};
EXPORT_SYMBOL(init_task);
```

Here are some important thins we need to make it clearly.

1. `INIT_THREAD_INFO(init_task)` sets the `thread_info`  as the graph above.
2. `init_stack` is defined as below

```c
extern unsigned long init_stack[THREAD_SIZE / sizeof(unsigned long)];
```

where  THREAD_SIZE equal to

```c
#ifdef CONFIG_KASAN
#define KASAN_STACK_ORDER 1
#else
#define KASAN_STACK_ORDER 0
#endif
#define THREAD_SIZE_ORDER   (2 + KASAN_STACK_ORDER)
#define THREAD_SIZE  (PAGE_SIZE << THREAD_SIZE_ORDER)
```

so the default size is defined.

3. The process 0 will only run in kernel space, but in some circumstances as I mention above it needs a virtual memory space, so we set the following

```c
    .mm     = NULL,
    .active_mm  = &init_mm,
```

Let's look back at `start_kernel`, the `rest_init` will initialize `kernel_init` and `kthreadd`.

```c
noinline void __ref rest_init(void)
{
......
    pid = kernel_thread(kernel_init, NULL, CLONE_FS);
......
    pid = kernel_thread(kthreadd, NULL, CLONE_FS | CLONE_FILES);
......
}
```

`kernel_init` will run `execve` and then go to user space, change to `init` process by running , which is process 1.

```c
if (!try_to_run_init_process("/sbin/init") || 
    !try_to_run_init_process("/etc/init")  || 
    !try_to_run_init_process("/bin/init")  || 
    !try_to_run_init_process("/bin/sh")) 
   return 0;
```

`kthread` becomes the daemon process to manage and schedule other kernel `task_struts`, which is process 2.

After all this, the process 0 will become idle process and jump out `rq` which means it will only run when the `rq` is empty.

```c
noinline void __ref rest_init(void)
{
......
    /*
     * The boot idle thread must execute schedule()
     * at least once to get things moving:
     */
    schedule_preempt_disabled();
    /* Call into cpu_idle with preempt disabled */
    cpu_startup_entry(CPUHP_ONLINE);
}


void cpu_startup_entry(enum cpuhp_state state)
{
    arch_cpu_idle_prepare();
    cpuhp_online_idle(state);
    while (1)
        do_idle();
}
```

Finally, here is a good [gitbook](https://0xax.gitbooks.io/linux-insides/content/) for you if you want to get more understanding of Linux kernel.

Comment: thanks, very helpful information! To be accurate, rather than the set_task_stack_end_magic which still does preparation work, is it fair to say that process 0 is started by this line "movq initial_stack(%rip), %rsp" in /arch/x86/kernel/head_64.S, since it is this line that fills RSP with process 0's kernel stack?

Comment: I think you mix the `init_task` and `init_stack`. They're not the same thing. The process 0 is build by gcc structure initialization as I mension above, you can think it just like we put a "int a = 1" in a program.

Comment: Not exactly. I'll update the post to make it clear.

Comment: Maybe you can edit my answer to make it complete. I think your edition now can completely solve the problem.

Comment: Yep, initially I'd suggest replacing the description of function set_task_stack_end_magic to the mov instruction mentioned above, and be done with it. But then when I started to write down a summary for myself, a lot more relevant stuff came in, some of those I am not quite sure, such as 'all idle threads share tid 0', which sounds a bit unreal to me.

Comment: I think your post is almost right, but still not perfct. So I edit my answer by myself.

Comment: Please help me to check if there are anything left or wrong